# Local CDN emulation for Safari?

Tags: safari, privacy, safari-extensions

I'm looking for a Safari extension that will function like this one:

https://decentraleyes.org

The idea is to bypass CDNs because many of these are hosted on domains (by Google and others) that are blocked on my computer.

Is there something like this out there?